How can I capture integrated fingerprint data from an android tablet to my browser webapp?
I have a tablet with an inbuilt fingerprint scanner and I want to access the fingerprint data from the device into my NextJS app, I've been looking for libraries to do that but no luck.
However the device came with an android app that can access this features, but it is of no use to me as I need to capture users' fingerprints directly in my webappPicture of device i am using and save them to my database.
I haven't tried any workaround this issue as I dont even have any idea where to start. Although I have the SDK or source code for the app that works with this features and it's written in Java.
